# Angular not returning my custom JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out this. I'm generating JSON in a file in my server, and I want Angular to return it, but it's failing to do so. The overall code is ok, it returns other JSON data from other files, as it follows in the example:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/0y9r05g2/
```

The non-working file containing JSON I want to use is this one:

```
http://paulogabriel.me/extranet/labs/angularjs-jobboard/js/list.json
```

Do you have any idea why my file is not being read by Angular? I've tested it and it's valid JSON. Is this a server issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show code please?

Comment: You did of course open the console and checked that it's just not a same-origin issue

Comment: Where do you see the code @adeneo ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Dsafds paste the jsfiddle link in your browser.

Comment: Open up the browser debugging tool, the console (F12), and check for errors.

Comment: @adeneo no errors at all.

Comment: Then you should post the code that's not working

Comment: @adeneo I did. The JSFIDDLE links shows my angular code works with other json files, and after that I link to the JSON I want to use (which is not working).

Comment: Posting a working Fiddle, and telling us it doesn't work with some other url on your website, doesn't help us, there's no way for us to see the problem, and any non-working code should **be in the question**.

Comment: It was because it was http// @adeneo as said in anwser..

Comment: @Dsafds - maybe, if the OP is using strict SSL that doesn't allow non-SSL content on his own server as well, just like jsFiddle does. Otherwise, it's probably the same-origin policy, as you've used Github, which adds the correct cross-origin headers as well. Both these issues will throw a clear error message in the console though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working was because your JSON File was in a http:// adress whitch JSFiddle Does not accept since it was not secure.. I was good enough to just put it in a github i did not use for real: https://cdn.rawgit.com/amanuel2/Collabs/master/list.json

Now after this it worked:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('vagasApp', []);

  app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    var url = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/amanuel2/Collabs/master/list.json"
    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
      $scope.apps = response;
    });
  });
})();
```

[**`Working Fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/0y9r05g2/9/)

Comment: That's a bingo!
I guess it's not just JSFiddle that doesn't accept it... my server doesn't accept it, not even my local machine accepts it. Well, I gotta figure how to setup a secure connection. Thank you, mate!

Comment: No Problem @PauloGabriel ! Btw just a hint hint, you can make a "useless" rep in github then just post "useless" JSON(Or any code files), then you click raw and get the url for production here: https://rawgit.com/

Comment: besides securing the sites, if the client app(angular) domain and server app domain is different then you will encounter the same problem. To avoid that you have to consider adding cross-domain * headers in server code.

Comment: @Dsafds does it mean it delivers files in a secure connection?

Comment: I mean https:// was preety much added for security @PauloGabriel . Http is Hyper Text Transfer Protocol  and Https is Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure. [**`More Info`**](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html)

Comment: @Dsafds thank you for taking your time to help me out!

Comment: @adeneo No, I don't have a certificate. Since I don't use it for more sensitive data I figured it wasn't necessary. Maybe it is.

Comment: Paulo what @adeneo is trying to say is that In the Chrome Console there is a tab called network.. There when you click refresh it tells you the files that got loaded, or not loaded. If not loaded specifies error. I highly reccomend you get some training with learning to use the console.

Comment: @Dsafds I didn't need it much until now... much of my work only needs a shallow inspect... but I should definitely learn more about it!